# Calculating a limit involving roots and logarithms

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm working on a problem, and after some simplification, I encounter with this limit.

> Is the result of this limit greater than $1$?
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[\beta -1]{1-(\frac{n^{\frac{1}{\beta-1}}}{\log{n}})^{2-\beta}}} + \frac{(\log{n})^{2-\beta}}{(\log{n})^{3-\beta}} > 1, \qquad \beta> 3$$

I don't know how we can solve this problem. Can anyone prove this relation?

Comment: Is the $log$ base $10$?

Comment: the $log$ is base $c$ which $c$ is a constant.

Comment: This looks annoying to do, but straightforward. Factor the $n^{1/(\beta - 1)}/\log n$ term out of the initial radical so that you are left with a radical that looks like $(1 - f(n))^{1/(\beta - 1)}$ with $f(n) \to 0$. Take the first several terms of the binomial expansion here, and that will give you sufficiently many terms to evaluate the remaining limit. There may be a shorter way to handle this, but this is the "brute force" way.

Comment: Obviously,$${\sqrt[\beta -1]{1-(\frac{n^{\frac{1}{\beta-1}}}{\log{n}})^{2-\beta}}} + \frac{(\log{n})^{2-\beta}}{(\log{n})^{3-\beta}}$$ can be rewritten as
$$\sqrt[\beta -1]{1-\frac{(\log{n})^{\beta-2}}{n^{\frac{\beta-2}{\beta-1}}}} + \frac{1}{\log{n}},$$ so the limit is $1$.